# Prime Number Script Checker

Tags: bash, scripting

I am new to scripting. The script below checks if a number inputted is a prime number or divisible by 2. Why is the third line from the bottom needed (i=`expr $i + 1`). I commented that line out to see what the script would do and it hangs the script up. Please advise.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a number: "
read num
i=2

while [ $i -lt $num ]
do
  if [ `expr $num % $i` -eq 0 ]
  then
      echo "$num is not a prime number"
      echo "Since it is divisible by $i"
      exit
  fi
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done

echo "$num is a prime number "
```

Comment: There's no need for the external command `expr`; use `$(($num % $i))` in place of `\`expr $num % $i\``.

Comment: learn to add `set -x` (and `set +x`) to turn on/off debugging where you'll see the value of the variable that is used in each command. You would see `expr 2 + 1` the first time that `expr` line executed. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't increment `i`, then the test `[ $i -lt $num ]` will never be false, assuming `i` starts out less than `num`.

Comment: I get it now, if the number entered is a prime number greater than 2 it will run the loop until the i variable equals the number that was input, making the test false and printing that the number is a prime number.